# Training a Convnet on 300GB data

Tags: bigdata, convolutional-neural-network, numpy

I have a large training set of ~300GB (which is a subset of an even larger dataset ~15TB).

I am trying train a Convnet with Keras (Tensorflow backend) to do something similar to semantic segmentation.

I couldn't find any valuable resources to handle such large data. Any suggestions for best practices for such humungous data is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to load the whole dataset into memory at once. The only data you need in memory are the samples in a single training batch. Use the [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) method rather than `fit` to pass in an iterator that feeds samples to your model from disk rather than loading all of that data at once. [Here's a tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly.html) that discusses this more.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! The solution works well for me even though its a bit slow since multiple reads from the disk have to be made during every iteration.